# Java - ресурсы для обучения на русском онлайн

Tags: java

Добрый день! Может кто начинал как и я изучение Java с нуля, подскажите пожалуйста годные ресурсы, может книжки.. много воды в интернете..

Comment: Нет ничего годного, к сожалению придется просто плыть. просто берешь и читаешь все что только можешь. Обязательно практикуешь. Проходишь любые всевозможные бесплатные курсы если таковые есть. Пишешь свои простые приложения консольные. И где то месяца через 2-4 уже можешь что то да знать на среднем уровне в java core

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вот это книгу: OCA/OCP Java SE 7 (на английском). Я уже не помню где ее скачал, думаю сможете найти сами. Это великолепная книга. Рассказывается простым языком, но достаточно глубоко. Если не знаете англ. не беда, читайте со словарем (потом англ. очень пригодится).

Answer (score 1):

Изучение Java с нуля лучше всего дается по книге "Изучаем Java" (англ. "Head First Java"), авторы Кэти Сьерра и Берт Бейтс. Из личного опыта. С картинками, схемами, тонким юмором.

Answer (score -1):

JavaRush, SoloLearn и GeekBrains.
JavaRush - отличное интерактивное обучение в виде игры, условно бесплатно.
SoloLearn - с чуть корявым переводом на русский, хорошо выполнено, имеет мобильные приложения. Все прям как на уроке с тестовыми заданиями после прочтения и модулями.
GeekBrains - русский образовательный портал начинающих программистов. Есть так же бесплатные курсы для начинающих (12 видео) и другие видео с пометкой Java.

Comment: Читать подобные статьи для новичка это, пожалуй, худшее что можно посоветовать. Данные ресурсы служат скорее "шпаргалкам", нежели учат программировать.